# How to change the location the 'r' axis for matplotlib polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How to change the location the 'r' axis for matplotlib polar plot?

I am trying to change the location of the r axis in a polar plot.
At the moment it is being covered up by the data, but there is a gap in the data at theta = 340-360 degrees (in my real data example this is actually approx. 45 degrees) so it would be good if i could put axis labels there, in the data gap.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sampleSize=1000
az=[]
inc=[]
for i in range(sampleSize):
    az.append(random.randint(0,340)) #not to the full 360 to represent my natural gap in the data
    inc.append(random.randint(0,90))

plt.figure()
plt.polar(np.radians(az),inc,'o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way that I can think of is to use `.set_rgrids` method:

```
f=plt.figure()
ax = f.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], projection='polar')
ax.plot(np.radians(az), inc, 'o')
ax.set_rgrids([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90], angle=345.)
```

[image]