# How can I fix polar RGB imshow's xticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code:

```
def complex_to_rgb(complex_data, invert=False):
  from numpy import angle, max, pi, sin, zeros
  phase = angle(complex_data)
  amplitude = abs(complex_data)
  amplitude = amplitude/max(max(amplitude))
  A = zeros((complex_data.shape[0], complex_data.shape[1], 3))
  A[:,:,0] = .5*(sin(phase)+1)*amplitude
  A[:,:,1] = .5*(sin(phase+pi/2)+1)*amplitude
  A[:,:,2] = .5*(-sin(phase)+1)*amplitude
  if(invert):
    return 1-A
  else:
    return A

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

N = 1024
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

R = np.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)
PHI = np.arctan2(Y, X)

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(212, polar=True)

ax.imshow(complex_to_rgb(R*np.exp(1j*PHI)  * (R<1), invert=True))

ax.set_xticks([-.5, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi, 3*np.pi/2])
ax.set_yticks([0, N/3, 2*N/3, N])

ax.set_xticklabels(['', '$0$', r'$\pi/2$', r'$\pi$', r'$3\pi/2$'])
ax.set_yticklabels([])

fig.show()
```

Generates a nice HSV legend plot. Now I'd like to remove the `-.5` xtick, but that seems to mess everything up. Anyone know how to fix this? I already [reported it as a bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2827)

Comment: Well, I found a hack to use the odd tick as a line for the r-scale, but Matplotlib 1.3.1 forces me to use [private methods as described here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2549).

Comment: I also found an alternative non-private method to do the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480317/how-to-change-the-location-the-r-axis-for-matplotlib-polar-plot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [the bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2827), I can place the radial axis anywhere I want by specifying an explicit `extent` to `imshow`. Additionally, `rgrids` can be used to fix the angle of the tick labels.

```
def complex_to_rgb(complex_data, invert=False):
  from numpy import angle, max, pi, sin, zeros
  phase = angle(complex_data)
  amplitude = abs(complex_data)
  amplitude = amplitude/max(max(amplitude))
  A = zeros((complex_data.shape[0], complex_data.shape[1], 3))
  A[:,:,0] = .5*(sin(phase)+1)*amplitude
  A[:,:,1] = .5*(sin(phase+pi/2)+1)*amplitude
  A[:,:,2] = .5*(-sin(phase)+1)*amplitude
  if(invert):
    return 1-A
  else:
    return A

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

N = 1024
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

R = np.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)
PHI = np.arctan2(Y, X)

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

ax.imshow(complex_to_rgb(R*np.exp(1j*PHI)  * (R<1), invert=True), extent=[0,2*np.pi, 0,1024])

ax.set_rgrids([1,N/3,2*N/3], angle=45)
ax.set_xticks([0, np.pi/2, np.pi, 3*np.pi/2])
ax.set_yticks([0, N/3, 2*N/3, N])

ax.set_xticklabels([r'$0$', r'$\pi/2$', r'$\pi$', r'$3\pi/2$'])
ax.set_yticklabels([r'0', r'$1/3$', r'$2/3$', '1'])

fig.show()
```

Which results in:
[image: HSV legend]